# highlight a win forms checkbox when cursor is inside it

Tags: winforms

I have a checkbox with no text specified. Now whenever I tab down to this checkbox, it doesnot get highlighted.I even tried setting focus in checkbox_Enter() event. I checked for focus in this event and focus is there in this checkbox. How to get it highlighted so that user can know that the cursor is there in checkbox.

Comment: I will do it.Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

- Try putting just a space into the Checkbox

Or

- setting AutoSize to false
- Setting the size of the Checkbox

Then there may be somewhere for WinForms to draw the focus ret.

Otherwise you have to to custom draw the Checkbox, or draw the focus rec round the Checkbox yourself.

---

Whatever you do it will not look that good, as users expect the focus rec to be round the label of the checkbox, and you wish to have a checkbox with no label.

Comment: how to put space in checkbox.U mean to say,in checkbox_Enter() event.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to draw focus rectangle.I am using ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(Graphics,Rectangle).How to get the graphics in checkbox_Enter() event.According to my knowledge it is available in OnPaint event.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by the below mentioned way

Use a panel.Push the checkbox inside that panel.Set the dimensions of a panel as such that it looks like a rectangle around the checkbox.In checkbox_enter() event set the border

```
BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

And in checkbox_Leave() event set the border again to

```
BorderStyle.None;
```

So this way it will tell user that focus in inside the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

To make the checkbox appear highlighted I had it change color on got focus and change back on lost focus.

this part is in the Form1.Designer.cs:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {...
    ckBox1.GotFocus += new System.EventHandler(checkBox_Highlight);
    ckBox1.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(checkBox_EndHighlight);
    ckBox1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(checkBox_Highlight);
    ckBox1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(checkBox_EndHighlight);
     }
```

This part is in the Form1:

```
 private void checkBox_Highlight(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox control = (CheckBox)sender;
        control.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        control.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    }

    private void checkBox_EndHighlight(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox control = (CheckBox)sender;
        if (!control.Focused)
        {
            control.ForeColor = DefaultForeColor;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While tabbing, this puts a light blue shadow beneath the CheckBox on Enter and on Leave - at least on my Windows7:

```
    ...
    checkBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(check_Enter);
    checkBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(check_Leave);
    ...

    private void check_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((CheckBox)sender).BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    }

    private void check_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((CheckBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually the highlights comes on the text of the checkbox not the checkbox itself

So, if I was you, I would put any control in the background of my check box and give it the focus when my checkbox is focused, to have the same look of default controls highlights.

which will be shown to end users as checkbox highlights.

Comment: -1 as giving the focus to another control will stop the space bar changing the value of the checkbox.

Comment: here is the way, put button little bit bigger than your checkbox behind the checkbox.

then make his  flatStyle property to flat
and foreColor property to same color of your form background.

then on the click event of the button write this code
  checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;
*this solve the bug which "lan Ringrose" mentioned.

that's it